Pulp model is infeasible but gives feasible results
I am currently working on some code that is able to solve our distribution schedule each day, without having to have someone at the company do it every morning. Currently I have the following code:
data = [
    {
        "Day": "2024-07-10",
        "Location": "Depo",
        "Pick-up": "A",
        "Boxes": 11,
        "Weekday": "Wednesday",
        "Time to pickup": "12:30:00"
    },
    {
        "Day": "2024-07-10",
        "Location": "Depo",
        "Pick-up": "B",
        "Boxes": 2,
        "Weekday": "Wednesday",
        "Time to pickup": "12:30:00"
    },
    {
        "Day": "2024-07-10",
        "Location": "Depo",
        "Pick-up": "C",
        "Boxes": 5,
        "Weekday": "Wednesday",
        "Time to pickup": "12:00:00"
    }
]

df_stint = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Parameters
bus_capacity = 10
num_buses = 6

model = pulp.LpProblem("Bus_Optimization", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Decision variables
pickup_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Pickup",
                                    [(i, j) for i in range(num_buses) for j in range(len(df_stint))],
                                    cat = 'Binary')

dropoff_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Dropoff",
                                     [(i, k) for i in range(num_buses) for k in df_stint['Location'].unique()],
                                     cat='Binary')

# Split variables
split_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Split",
                                    [(i, j) for i in range(num_buses) for j in range(len(df_stint))],
                                    lowBound=0,
                                    cat='Integer')


# Objective: Minimize the number of buses used
model += pulp.lpSum([dropoff_vars[i, k] for i in range(num_buses) for k in df_stint['Location'].unique()])

# Constraint 1: each stint is picked up exactly once
for j in range(len(df_stint)):
    model += pulp.lpSum(pickup_vars[i, j] for i in range(num_buses)) == 1

# Constraint 2: capacity constraint
for i in range(num_buses):
    model += pulp.lpSum(df_stint.iloc[j]['Boxes'] * pickup_vars[i, j] for j in range(len(df_stint))) <= bus_capacity
    
# Constraint 3: split variables
for i in range(num_buses):
    for j in range(len(df_stint)):
        model += split_vars[i, j] <= df_stint.iloc[j]['Boxes'] * pickup_vars[i, j]
        
        
model.solve()
print(f"Status: {pulp.LpStatus[model.status]}")

# Results
for i in range(num_buses):
    for j in range(len(df_stint)):
        value = pulp.value(pickup_vars[i, j])
        if value > 0:
            print(f"Bus {i} picks up from {df_stint.iloc[j]['Pick-up']} to {df_stint.iloc[j]['Location']} and picked up {value * df_stint.iloc[j]['Boxes']} boxes")

print("\nConstraint Values:")
for name, constraint in model.constraints.items():
    value = constraint.value()
    print(f"{name}: {constraint} : {value}")

print("\nVariable Values:")
for var in model.variables():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.varValue}")

This code shows that there are three pick-up locations (where boxes are picked up) and currently (there are actually 4 locations but I'll scale the code) there is one location each box needs to be dropped off. There are 6 busses and every bus can hold 10 boxes. Eventually I want to be able to use busses when they are idle in between pickup and dropoff using the travel time between pick-up and location, but that is for later.
My problem is that the status of the model is infeasible, even though it does output a feasible schedule. Does anybody know why?

The problem is infeasible, as stated by the solver.  The solution produced is NOT a feasible solution.  The variable values are non-integer.  They likely represent some intermediate calculations, etc.  Bottom line:  if the solver says infeasible, don't bother to look at the variable values
